# Applying code from rows to the dataset pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

- I have manually wrote this:

  ```
  p = [[45.1024,7.7498],[45.1027,7.7513],[45.1072,7.7568],[45.1076,7.7563]]
  q = [[45.0595,7.6829],[45.0595,7.6829],[45.0564,7.6820],[45.0533,7.6796],[45.0501,7.6775]]
  ```
- To do this for NaN removing (suits me perfect):

  ```
  p = np.array([i for i in p if np.any(np.isfinite(i))], np.float64)
  q = np.array([i for i in q if np.any(np.isfinite(i))], np.float64)
  ```

## But when it comes to a data set:

```
    1           1.1     2           2.1     3           3.1     4           4.1     5           5.1
0   43.1024     6.7498  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
1   46.0595     1.6829  25.0695     3.7463  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
2   25.0695     5.5454  44.9727     8.6660  41.9726     2.6666  84.9566     3.8484  44.9566     1.8484
3   35.0281     7.7525  45.0322     3.7465  14.0369     3.7463  NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
```

I want to do same "NaN removing" process above with `df.iloc[0]` (with first row):

p = `df.iloc[0]` within `np.array([i for i in p if np.any(np.isfinite(i))], np.float64)`

Comment: What is your expected output? a single array with just the values `[43.1024,     6.7498]`?

Comment: @ALollz yes. for every row. Even with the loop in order to avoid same operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the arrays are of different length I think we're stuck with `apply`

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.array(x.dropna()), 1)
#0                                    [43.1024, 6.7498]
#1                   [46.0595, 1.6829, 25.0695, 3.7463]
#2    [25.0695, 5.5454, 44.9727, 8.666, 41.9726, 2.6...
#3    [35.0281, 7.7525, 45.0322, 3.7465, 14.0369, 3....
#dtype: object
```

---

#### `stack` + `groupby`.

Stacking removes `NaN` values when going from wide to long. This gets them all at once, then just pick the one you want. Probably similar or worse performance than above.

```
import numpy as np

s = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(np.array)
#0                                    [43.1024, 6.7498]
#1                   [46.0595, 1.6829, 25.0695, 3.7463]
#2    [25.0695, 5.5454, 44.9727, 8.666, 41.9726, 2.6...
#3    [35.0281, 7.7525, 45.0322, 3.7465, 14.0369, 3....
#dtype: object

s.iloc[0]
#array([43.1024,  6.7498])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this should work? `df.dropna()` 
 Question is unclear to me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all `Nan` values in your DataFrame, you can just loop through the columns and use `fillna` on it. I'm assuming you want it to be blank instead?

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[[col]] = df[[col]].fillna(value = '')
```

Or if you want to retain it's type to be `float`

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[[col]] = df[[col]].fillna(value = 0.0)
```